# CFWheels ORM and SQL Injection

Tags: coldfusion, cfwheels

I am new to Coldfusion and my previous background is in PHP using codeIgniter. I am currently using CFWheels for a project.

I have a insert statement

```
n_building = model("buildings").new();
n_building.name = name;
n_building.save();
```

And read statement

```
room = model("rooms").findOne(where="name='#name#' AND b_id='#b_id#'");
```

Is the above best practice or can it be written better in terms of security.

Question is that will using ORM automatically protect my queries from SQL Injection or any other form of injection or security risk? Do I have to use something else with it, if so how can I modify the above statements?

Comment: Have a look at dynamic finders http://docs.cfwheels.org/docs/dynamic-finders

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CfWheels by default uses cfqueryparam for everything unless you use parameter **parameterize** and set it to false. So you don't have to worry about the Sql injection.

Read about parameterize parameter in [findAll method description](http://docs.cfwheels.org/v1.4/docs/findall) .

Your code can be made better as suggested by John Whish by using dynamic finders.

Comment: clean answer! I have one question though: what does CFWheels does, if we also have in place a `Having` clause in the `group` attribute of the model statement? Will it parameterize the having clause as well? For example: 
room = model("rooms").findAll(select="count(id)",where="name='#name#' AND b_id='#b_id#'", group="room_type Having count(id) > 0");

This is just a simple example but you get the idea.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know cfwheels ORM will parametrize the queries built by the ORM.
It will insert `<cfqueryparam>` in the Statement.
But you could enable debugging and easily have a look at the query sent to the database.

Comment: This is correct. CFWheels will parse your `where` value and parameterize the values passed in.